# How can I get the list of facebook id of users that installed my app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

recently I create an application that uses facebook login.

I'm not storing the users data, but I'd like know the users facebook id.

How can I get the facebook id of the users that have installed my application?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, you cannot, you need to have your own database that saves that kind of data (everytime someone logs into the application with Facebook save his ID into your own database).

Comment: Also, just stumbled upon [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081147/get-list-of-facebook-users-who-are-using-specific-application-using-fql) because I wasn't quite sure.

Answer (score 0):

This is FQl Query:

`$facebook->api(array('method' => 'fql.query', 'query' => "SELECT uid FROM user WHERE is_app_user = '1' AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = '" . $user_id . "');"));`

The documentation for the user and friend queries are here:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/friend/